# Xamarin.forms ListView click to next page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am not able to pass the value(id) to the next page when I clicked on the specific list items.

My Xaml file

```
 <ListView  x:Name="Clublistview" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell Height="50">
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White"
                            Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Logo}" IsVisible="true" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

My .CS file

```
async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView btn = (ListView)sender;
        int clubid = (int)btn.CommandParameter;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailedClub(clubid));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have CommandParameter bound to anything.  A simpler approach would be

```
async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView lv = (ListView)sender;

    // this assumes your List is bound to a List<Club>
    Club club = (Club) lv.SelectedItem;

    // assuiming Club has an Id property
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailedClub(club.Id));
}
```